# COM Registration without Version Identifier

Tags: .net, com

Is it possible to register a COM interface independent of assembly version?

Right now I get a registry key like

```
MyIfaceName, Version=1.0.3259.17799, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890abcdef
```

But since the assembly has auto-versioning (`1.0.*.*`), every day I do a new build the COM-iface needs to be re-registered.

How would I register without specifying a version?  What are the consequences of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) to generate the COM wrapper you can use the /codebase parameter which creates a Codebase entry in the registry.

> The Codebase entry specifies the file
>   path for an assembly that is not
>   installed in the global assembly
>   cache.

You can then easily update the assembly without the need of re-registering it if the interface hasn't changed of course.